# Grunt : Adding an alias to a non-project folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs

I have set up a basic project to test some of the CSS that our designers are creating for another application.  My aim is to provide a set of static html files that can be styled by CSS locally, before it is uploaded to our content management system.

Currently I have the following file structure:

```
Base/app/Gruntfile.js

Base/app/brand1/index.html
Base/app/brand2/index.html

Base/StaticContent/brand1/css/file.css
Base/StaticContent/brand2/css/file.css
```

The index.html files reference static CSS and JS files from `/static_files/brand1/StaticContent`

When I run `grunt serve` I would like to go to `http://localhost:9000/brand1/index.html` and have the css files load from `../StaticContent/brand1/css/file.css` when it attempts to load it from `/static_files/brand1/StaticContent/css/file.css`.

I want to know how to alias or proxy `/static_files/brand1/StaticContent` to `../StaticContent/brand1`

I am relatively inexperienced with front end development, but I'm attempting to make our design process a lot simpler for our designers.  I am default yeoman webapp application, so only have the default grunt plugins supplied with this.

Current gruntfile.js is

```
// Generated on 2016-01-12 using
// generator-webapp 1.1.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// If you want to recursively match all subfolders, use:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
  });

  // Configurable paths
  var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      babel: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:dist']
      },
      babelTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:test', 'test:watch']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      sass: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'postcss']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'postcss']
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      options: {
        notify: false,
        background: true,
        watchOptions: {
          ignored: ''
        }
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          files: [
            '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*',
            '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ],
          port: 9000,
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          open: false,
          logLevel: 'silent',
          host: 'localhost',
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', './test', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          background: false,
          server: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= config.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    eslint: {
      target: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
        'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://<%= browserSync.test.options.host %>:<%= browserSync.test.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },

    // Compiles ES6 with Babel
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapEmbed: true,
        sourceMapContents: true,
        includePaths: ['.']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
          // Add vendor prefixed styles
          require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']
          })
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
        exclude: ['bootstrap.js'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= config.dist %>',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      },
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true,
          // true would impact styles with attribute selectors
          removeRedundantAttributes: false,
          useShortDoctype: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: '{,*/}*.html',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            'images/{,*/}*.webp',
            '{,*/}*.html',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '.',
          src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
      dist: {
        devFile: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
          ]
        },
        uglify: true
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'babel:dist',
        'sass'
      ],
      test: [
        'babel'
      ],
      dist: [
        'babel',
        'sass',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', function (target) {

    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'browserSync:dist']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss',
      'browserSync:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
      grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'postcss'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'browserSync:test',
      'mocha'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:eslint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Weird setup, it would SO much easier if you just got the CSS and HTML into the same directory. Grunt isnt setup to do this.

Comment: Yes, weird setup.  I want to provide the design team the ability to be able to test their changes locally, without polluting the existing folders, as only the css is taken and uploaded to the CMS system (OpenText WEM).  Adding any framework into the path of the existing style sheets would mean a change to the existing procedures, and I'm not sure they could cope with that.

Comment: Try getting the path with node.path in my answer below - you should be able to parse that into what you need. It's still hacky but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking, in essence, is if Grunt can watch a parent file. All the [globbing patterns for Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) follow Node.js conventions, so you could try playing with them.

But natively, grunt is watching child files, not parent files. You'd have to hack it I think, maybe using [node's path utility](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and then manually parsing that string to feed back into your `usemin` task. I don't know if the juice is worth the squeeze - just move your CSS and HTML into the same directory (or at least a sub directory of `app`) and all of this gets really easy.

Some other pointers that may help:

- Your current grunt file is making use of a utility called [`grunt-usemin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-usemin), which performs the rewrites. Your watch task, at the top of the file, is setup to look for CSS files at '/styles'. If styles aren't there, they won't load properly.
- Near the bottom of your file is the `grunt.registerTask('build',` area - this is called as a dependency whenever you run `grunt serve`. It's setup properly from the looks of it.
- Your grunt file has commented out the `cssmin` functionality. That's ok but it requires you put your CSS files in a *very* specific place (read the comment in your code). Uncomment these lines if you didn't put your CSS/SCSS in the right place.
- You could also add `grunt-rewrite` to your file, which does something similar but should be unnecessary given you already have `grunt-usemin` in there.